# Parse lambda from a string to validate input

Tags: c#, validation, parsing, lambda

I am setting up credentials defined by one user to validate input from another user. is there a way to generate a lambda from a string to check another string if it marches the criteria of the first string in my c# program?

```
    void someFunction
    {
       string lambdastring = getlambdastringFromUser1();
       string needToValidate = getStringToValidateFromUser2();
       if(!validByLambda(lambdastring, needToValidate))
       {
          doSomething();
       }
    }

    bool validByLambda(string l, string v)
    {
       return ?What goes here?
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a simple solution for this. Instead, you could provide a regex expression for validation. Those can be evaluated at runtime. See: [Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) and [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Comment: It would be much easier to use regex instead of constructing lambda from string. However it is possible with `Linq.Expressions`. What kind of input are you expecting from first user?